# Unable to make api request to backend getting Axios network error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, axios

```
I was making one app with frontend react.js uses axios to api call and for backend i am using express and node with database mysql while making call to api url i am getting error for access denied error

    Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

If this is not the case i will be getting axios network error

    Axios Network error

 i dont know which port to use if i use 3306 port it is already in use. Please take a look at code and suggest about optimization and a better way...


thank you....
```

config.js will be saving confiq for the connection db
config.js

```js
const config = {
      db: {
        host: "localhost",
        user: "new_user",
        password: "password",
        database: "db",

      },
    };

    module.exports = config;
```

```
db.js will create the connection
db.js
```

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
    const config = require("./config");

    var con = mysql.createPool(config);

    module.exports = con;
```

this is where the express and app server is supposed to create
index.js

```js
    const express = require("express");
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const app = express();
    app.use(express());
    app.use(cors());
    const TablesRoutes = require("./routes/TablesRoutes");
    //routes
    app.use("/", TablesRoutes);



    app.listen(8000, () => {
      console.log("Running on port :8000");
    });
```

api routes to call from frontend
routes

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const {
      postTableDes,
      alterTable,
      showTables,
    } = require("../Controllers/Tables");
    const tablerouter = express.Router();

    tablerouter.get("/", showTables);
    tablerouter.post("/", postTableDes);

    module.exports= tablerouter;
```

where showing the table act
controller

```js
    const con = require("../Config/db");
    //get tables
    const showTables = async (req, res) => {
      //try {
        var sql = `show tables`;
        const data = await con.query(sql, (err, res)=>{
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(404).json({ error: "No show table" });
            return;
          }
          console.log(res);
          res.status(202).json(data);
        });
     module.exports = showTables;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `config.js` to (the `createPool` call does not expect an object with `db` property):

```
const config = {
   host: "localhost",
   user: "new_user",
   password: "password",
   database: "db",
};

module.exports = config;
```